# Installing application developed in both VS 2010 and VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, setup-deployment

A mixed-mode (managed/unmanaged) application that contains DevXpress Windows Forms and WPF components was successfully installing when using a VS2010 Setup & Deployment project. After some Windows Updates were pushed to users, the installation failed with the message:

> "Error writing to file: C:\Users\auser\AppData\roaming\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory."

All users are administrators of their PC's. When reading the installation log provided by msiexec, the only errors were related to a bitmap exceeding the size of a window. Our code has no explicit dependency on Interactivity.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by not using VS2013. It seems you need to keep a homogeneous development environment. I have no explanation for the error message.

Comment: It's generally best to not provide an answer when you don't have a full understanding of the problem.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - if someone had posted this information that I did, it would have saved my team a lot of time.